# jQuery append images from other divs to a selected div

Tags: jquery, image, append, gallery

I've created an image gallery for some magazine issues, I'm wanting to style it like something in my images attached but I'm not sure if you can do what I'm after,

I basically want to jQuery append the image from div 1 and 3 and drop it behind the image on the div currently selected (div 2).

Thanks in advance for any help.

I've also got a js fiddle for the code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/5Z39B/1/

[image]

jQuery

```
 var issueTotal = 0;

$('#backIssue0').show();

$('.prevButton').hide();    

$('.nextButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    issueTotal = issueTotal + 1;

    if(issueTotal > 0){
        $('.prevButton').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal < 4){
        $('.nextButton').show();
    }    
    if(issueTotal > 3){
        $('.nextButton').hide();
    }

    $("#backIssue" + issueTotal).show();
    if(issueTotal > 0) {
        $('#backIssue' + (issueTotal - 1)).hide();
    }

});


$('.prevButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    issueTotal = issueTotal - 1;

    if(issueTotal > 1){
        $('.prevButton').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal < 1){
        $('.prevButton').hide();
    }
    if(issueTotal < 4){
        $('.nextButton').show();
    }    
    if(issueTotal > 3){
        $('.nextButton').hide();
    }

    $("#backIssue" + issueTotal).show();
    if(issueTotal > 0) {
        $('#backIssue' + (issueTotal - 1)).hide();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
 <div id="buttons">
     <a href="#" class="prevButton">PREVIOUS</a>
     <a href="#" class="nextButton">NEXT</a>
 </div>
 <div id=issueContainer>
 <div id="backIssue0">
     <img src="http://www.tuwidesign.com/tuwi/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/web_designer_magazine.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
 </div>
 <div id="backIssue1">
     <img src="http://blogof.francescomugnai.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/cover_web_designer.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
 </div>
 <div id="backIssue2">
     <img src="http://www.onerutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/WD189.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
 </div>
 <div id="backIssue3">
     <img src="http://www.ukhumourweb.co.uk/web-design-201.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
 </div>
 <div id="backIssue4">
     <img src="http://www.solidshops.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/web-designer-magazine1.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 #backIssue0{width:100px;display:none; float:left;}
 #backIssue1{width:100px;display:none;float:left;}
 #backIssue2{width:100px;display:none;float:left;}
 #backIssue3{width:100px;display:none;float:left;}
 #backIssue4{width:100px;display:none;float:left;}
 .nextButton{margin-left:50px;}
 .previousButton{}
 #issueContainer{width:100px;height:130px; overflow:hidden;}
 #buttons{clear:both;}​
               ​
```

​

Comment: First you should try layout things yourself, and after that ask question about specific problems. We can't do all work for you :)

Comment: Just try to use an "ready to use" plugin or maybe you could read the code and get inspired: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/

Comment: @andrewpey I'm not wanting someone to do it for me, I just wanted to know if it was possible and what methods might be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aEvhh/

How's this?

Html:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="prevButton">PREVIOUS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nextButton">NEXT</a>
</div>
<div id=issueContainer>
<div id="backIssue0" class="issue">
    <img src="http://www.tuwidesign.com/tuwi/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/web_designer_magazine.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
</div>
<div id="backIssue1" class="issue">
    <img src="http://blogof.francescomugnai.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/cover_web_designer.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
</div>
<div id="backIssue2" class="issue">
    <img src="http://www.onerutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/WD189.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
</div>
<div id="backIssue3" class="issue">
    <img src="http://www.ukhumourweb.co.uk/web-design-201.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
</div>
<div id="backIssue4" class="issue">
    <img src="http://www.solidshops.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/web-designer-magazine1.jpg" width="100" alt="#" />
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var issueTotal = 0;
function update_issues(){
    $('.issue').removeClass('comingup').hide();
    if(issueTotal >0){
        console.log('#backIssue' + (issueTotal -1));
     $('#backIssue' + (issueTotal -1)).addClass('comingup').show();   
    }
    $('#backIssue' + (issueTotal )).show();
    if(issueTotal <4){
     $('#backIssue' + (issueTotal +1)).addClass('comingup').show();  
    }
    if(issueTotal > 0){
        $('.prevButton').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal < 4){
        $('.nextButton').show();
    }    
}


    $('.nextButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        issueTotal = issueTotal + 1;
        update_issues();
    });
    update_issues();

    $('.prevButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        issueTotal = issueTotal - 1;
        update_issues();

    });
```

CSS:

```
.issue { width:100px;display:none;float:left;}
.nextButton{margin-left:50px;}
.previousButton{}
#issueContainer{width:300px;height:130px; overflow:hidden;}
.issue.comingup { opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */ }
#buttons{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Thanks thats very helpful, I'm sure I can have a play around with this example.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using jQuery, have you considered using a plugin for the work ?

[**Roundabout**](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) is a jQuery plugin that easily converts unordered lists & other nested HTML structures into entertaining, interactive, turntable-like areas.

It’s open source and released under the BSD license, meaning that it’s free to use in your personal or commercial projects.

Demo with images:

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/images

[image: Images Demo]

Demo with 3D effects:

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/3d

[image: 3D Demo]

You can also extend it with new effects with [Roundabout Shapes](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout-shapes)

[image: Shapes effects]